# How to retrieve a friendly ICC profile name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, color-profile, color-management

Is there a way in C# to retrieve a friendly ICC Profile name. For example:

```
string GetICCProfileFriendlyName(string fileRef)
{
   ...
}
```

Probably using P/Invoke, gdi32.dll, ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Color.ColorContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.colorcontext.aspx) that you can use to get a ProfileUri. However I am not sure if this only works with WPF or if it works with WinForms too.

Comment: Ah ok. You need a .NET 2.0 solution?

Comment: You will probably have to manually parse this out. See the PDF [here](http://www.color.org/icc_specs2.xalter)